# Select all the values within Materialize Multiple Select

Tags: jquery, materialize

I m using materialize multiple Select. The values in select are populated through ajax returned data through jquery.

Then i want to select all the values in multiple select with a function call which is attached to a check box. i m using following code to implement this scenario

```
function selectAllAges()

$('#agerange').material_select();
    $('#agerange').val(values);
    $('#agerange').material_select();

}
```

The problem is that it does not select all the values and don't show the checkboxes checked inside the select. Kindly help me to solve it.

Comment: you can try to select each value independently

Comment: what is "values" ? (provide sample object)

Comment: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"]

Comment: Values are selected but it is not reflected in the UI that the checkboxes inside the select are checked. Tried too many solutions but nothings works.

Answer (score 0):

change the first one

`$('#agerange').material_select();`

by:

`$('#agerange').material_select('destroy');`

and then it will work!

```js
function selectAllAges(){

    $('#agerange').material_select('destroy');
    $('#agerange').val(values);
    $('#agerange').material_select();

}
```